# how to make active and inactive on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

> How to make buttons active and inactive on click? am having 5 button each one has its own function. when click on A button some animation will start continuously,if click on same A button how to stop animation, how to make rest of the four buttons has to disable and when click on the active one rest of the buttons has to disable.thanks in advance (suppose if A is clicked it has to active and B C D E has to be disabled and if A is clicked again it has to come to normal state B C D E has to enable)

```js
function bubbles() { 
$.each($(".particletext.bubbles"), function(){
var bubblecount = 4;
for(var i = 0; i <= bubblecount; i++) {
var size = ((Math.floor( Math.random() * (80 - 40 + 1) ) + 40)/10);
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + 27 + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (95 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
}); 
}


function hearts() {
$.each($(".particletext.hearts"), function(){
var heartcount = 3;
for(var i = 0; i <= heartcount; i++) {
var size = ((Math.floor( Math.random() * (120 - 60 + 1) ) + 60)/10);
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + 11 + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (95 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function confetti() {
$.each($(".particletext.confetti"), function(){
var confetticount = 4;
for(var i = 0; i <= confetticount; i++) {
$(this).append('<span class="particle c' +(Math.floor( Math.random() * (2 - 1 + 1) ) + 1) + '" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (50 - 10 + 1) ) + 10) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (100 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (8 - 6 + 1) ) + 6)+ 'px; height:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (4 - 3+ 1) ) + 3) + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function fire() {
$.each($(".particletext.fire"), function(){
var firecount = 2;
for(var i = 0; i <= firecount; i++) {
var size = Math.floor( Math.random() * (12 - 8 + 1) ) + 8;
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (70 - 40 + 1) ) + 40) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (1 +20 + 11) ) + 1) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function sunbeams() {
$.each($(".particletext.sunbeams"), function(){
var linecount = 3;
for(var i = 0; i <= linecount; i++) {
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (0 + 40 + 1) ) - 40) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (100 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' +(Math.floor( Math.random() * (2 - 1 + 1) ) + 1 )+ 'px; height:' + 35 + '%;animation-delay: -' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}
```

```css
.particletext {
text-align: center;
font-size: 48px;
position: relative;
}
.particletext.bubbles > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(33, 149, 243, 0.603);
-webkit-animation: bubbles 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: bubbles 3s ease-in infinite;
border-radius: 100%;
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(204,42,93,1);
-webkit-animation: hearts 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: hearts 3s ease-in infinite;
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:before,.particletext.hearts > .particle:after {
position: absolute;
content: '';
border-radius: 100px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(204,42,93,1);
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:before {
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:after {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.particletext.lines > .particle {
position: absolute; 
background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.5);
-webkit-animation: lines 3s linear infinite;
animation: lines 3s linear infinite;
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
-webkit-animation: confetti 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: confetti 3s ease-in infinite;
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle.c1 {
background-color: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.5);
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle.c2 {
background-color: rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.5);
}
.particletext.fire > .particle {
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(7, 141, 255, 0.5);
border-radius: 40px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
-webkit-animation: fires 0.8s linear infinite;
animation: fires 0.8s linear infinite;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
opacity: 0;
}
.particletext.fire > .particle:before {
position: absolute;
content: '';
top: 60%;
left: 40%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
border-radius: 40px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
background-color: rgba(0, 66, 251, 0.5);
}
.particletext.sunbeams > .particle {
position: absolute;
background-color:#dc3dd5;
border-radius: 100px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-animation: sunbeams 3s linear infinite;
animation: sunbeams 3s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bubbles {
0% {
opacity: 0;
}
20% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%);
transform: translate(0, -20%);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%);
transform: translate(0, -1000%);
}
} 
@keyframes bubbles {
0% {
opacity: 0;
}
20% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%);
transform: translate(0, -20%);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%);
transform: translate(0, -1000%);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes hearts {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
}
20% {
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
 transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
}
}
@keyframes hearts {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
}
20% {
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes lines {
0%, 50%, 100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
transform: translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
transform: translateY(100%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
}
@keyframes lines {
0%, 50%, 100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
transform: translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
transform: translateY(100%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes confetti {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
}
10% {
opacity: 1;
}
35% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
}
80% {
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
}
}
@keyframes confetti {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
}
10% {
opacity: 1;
}
35% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
}
80% {
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fires {
0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
opacity: 1;
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
opacity: 1;
}
}
@keyframes fires {
0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
opacity: 1;
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
opacity: 1;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes sunbeams {
0% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
}
0%,14%,17%,43%,53%,71%,80%,94%,100% {
opacity: 0;
}
6%,15%,24%,28%,48%,55%,78%,82%,99% {
opacity: 1;
}
}
@keyframes sunbeams {
0% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
}
0%,14%,17%,43%,53%,71%,80%,94%,100% {
opacity: 0;
}
6%,15%,24%,28%,48%,55%,78%,82%,99% {
opacity: 1;
}
}

ul.socialIcons {
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.socialIcons li {
background: #fff;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 25px;
font-size: 12px;
}


.socialIcons li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="socialIcons">
<li class="particletext hearts" onclick="hearts()"><a>A</a></li>
<li class="particletext bubbles" onclick="bubbles()"><a>B</a></li>
<li class="particletext sunbeams" onclick="sunbeams()"><a>C</a></li>
<li class="particletext confetti" onclick="confetti()"><a>D</a></li>
<li class="particletext fire" onclick="fire()"><a>E</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you pass animation as argument instead of defining separate function for each animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aryana here's the solution last time you've wanted. Now when a button is clicked it will fire its animation and you can stop it by clicking it again. And if any other dissable button is clicked other buttons and any of their running animation will stop and the animation of this button will be fired. 
I made some change in js file and html file. And changes are indicated by comments.

```js
// My code starts here

var clickedElement = ""; //track the click element
var elementClassName;

$('.particletext').click(function () {
  
  $('.particletext').children('span').remove(); //remove animation for click
  elementClassName = $(this).attr('class'); 
  
  if (clickedElement == elementClassName) { //if the same element is clicked again then it simply null the clickedElement
      clickedElement = "";
  } else { //if different element is clicked then it store the element class in clickedElement and fires the respective animation animation
    
      clickedElement = elementClassName;
      elementFunctionName = (elementClassName.split(" "))[1];
  
      if (elementFunctionName == "hearts") {
          hearts();
      } else if (elementFunctionName == "bubbles") {
          bubbles();
      } else if (elementFunctionName == "sunbeams") {
          sunbeams();
      } else if (elementFunctionName == "confetti") {
          confetti();
      } else if (elementFunctionName == "fire") {
          fire();
      }
   
  }
  
})

// My code ends here

function stopAnimation(element) {
  $(element).children('span').remove(); //remove animating particles
  
  //for second click re-add onclick functions to all elements
  $('.hearts').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "hearts()");
    $(this).attr("onclick");
  })
  
  $('.bubbles').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "bubbles()");
    $(this).attr("onclick");
  })
  $('.sunbeams').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "sunbeams()");
  })
  $('.confetti').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "confetti()");
  })
  $('.fire').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "fire()");
  })
}

function bubbles() { 
$.each($(".particletext.bubbles"), function(){
var bubblecount = 4;
for(var i = 0; i <= bubblecount; i++) {
var size = ((Math.floor( Math.random() * (80 - 40 + 1) ) + 40)/10);
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + 27 + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (95 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
}); 
}


function hearts() {
$.each($(".particletext.hearts"), function(){
var heartcount = 3;
for(var i = 0; i <= heartcount; i++) {
var size = ((Math.floor( Math.random() * (120 - 60 + 1) ) + 60)/10);
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + 11 + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (95 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function confetti() {
$.each($(".particletext.confetti"), function(){
var confetticount = 4;
for(var i = 0; i <= confetticount; i++) {
$(this).append('<span class="particle c' +(Math.floor( Math.random() * (2 - 1 + 1) ) + 1) + '" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (50 - 10 + 1) ) + 10) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (100 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (8 - 6 + 1) ) + 6)+ 'px; height:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (4 - 3+ 1) ) + 3) + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function fire() {
$.each($(".particletext.fire"), function(){
var firecount = 2;
for(var i = 0; i <= firecount; i++) {
var size = Math.floor( Math.random() * (12 - 8 + 1) ) + 8;
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (70 - 40 + 1) ) + 40) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (1 +20 + 11) ) + 1) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function sunbeams() {
$.each($(".particletext.sunbeams"), function(){
var linecount = 3;
for(var i = 0; i <= linecount; i++) {
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (0 + 40 + 1) ) - 40) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (100 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' +(Math.floor( Math.random() * (2 - 1 + 1) ) + 1 )+ 'px; height:' + 35 + '%;animation-delay: -' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}
```

```css
.particletext {
text-align: center;
font-size: 48px;
position: relative;
}
.particletext.bubbles > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(33, 149, 243, 0.603);
-webkit-animation: bubbles 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: bubbles 3s ease-in infinite;
border-radius: 100%;
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(204,42,93,1);
-webkit-animation: hearts 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: hearts 3s ease-in infinite;
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:before,.particletext.hearts > .particle:after {
position: absolute;
content: '';
border-radius: 100px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(204,42,93,1);
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:before {
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:after {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.particletext.lines > .particle {
position: absolute; 
background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.5);
-webkit-animation: lines 3s linear infinite;
animation: lines 3s linear infinite;
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
-webkit-animation: confetti 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: confetti 3s ease-in infinite;
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle.c1 {
background-color: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.5);
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle.c2 {
background-color: rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.5);
}
.particletext.fire > .particle {
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(7, 141, 255, 0.5);
border-radius: 40px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
-webkit-animation: fires 0.8s linear infinite;
animation: fires 0.8s linear infinite;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
opacity: 0;
}
.particletext.fire > .particle:before {
position: absolute;
content: '';
top: 60%;
left: 40%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
border-radius: 40px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
background-color: rgba(0, 66, 251, 0.5);
}
.particletext.sunbeams > .particle {
position: absolute;
background-color:#dc3dd5;
border-radius: 100px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-animation: sunbeams 3s linear infinite;
animation: sunbeams 3s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bubbles {
0% {
opacity: 0;
}
20% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%);
transform: translate(0, -20%);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%);
transform: translate(0, -1000%);
}
} 
@keyframes bubbles {
0% {
opacity: 0;
}
20% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%);
transform: translate(0, -20%);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%);
transform: translate(0, -1000%);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes hearts {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
}
20% {
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
 transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
}
}
@keyframes hearts {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
}
20% {
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes lines {
0%, 50%, 100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
transform: translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
transform: translateY(100%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
}
@keyframes lines {
0%, 50%, 100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
transform: translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
transform: translateY(100%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes confetti {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
}
10% {
opacity: 1;
}
35% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
}
80% {
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
}
}
@keyframes confetti {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
}
10% {
opacity: 1;
}
35% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
}
80% {
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fires {
0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
opacity: 1;
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
opacity: 1;
}
}
@keyframes fires {
0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
opacity: 1;
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
opacity: 1;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes sunbeams {
0% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
}
0%,14%,17%,43%,53%,71%,80%,94%,100% {
opacity: 0;
}
6%,15%,24%,28%,48%,55%,78%,82%,99% {
opacity: 1;
}
}
@keyframes sunbeams {
0% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
}
0%,14%,17%,43%,53%,71%,80%,94%,100% {
opacity: 0;
}
6%,15%,24%,28%,48%,55%,78%,82%,99% {
opacity: 1;
}
}

ul.socialIcons {
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.socialIcons li {
background: #fff;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 25px;
font-size: 12px;
}


.socialIcons li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- all onclick methods are removed -->
<ul class="socialIcons">
<li class="particletext hearts"><a>A</a></li>
<li class="particletext bubbles"><a>B</a></li>
<li class="particletext sunbeams"><a>C</a></li>
<li class="particletext confetti"><a>D</a></li>
<li class="particletext fire"><a>E</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when i refresh the page animation stops,   but am wondering if it is possible  after refresh page also animation not to sop until i click to stop on it @Showrin Barua

Comment: No. There is no such way. Because when you refresh the page it will reload html, js, css files. That's why all are restarted after refreshing. @aryana

Comment: are you facing problem with the code above? can you give me a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution of your problem. I've added some lines of code at the top of the js file. I added comments for better understanding. Hope it'll help you.

```js
var click = 0; //track the click

$('.particletext').click(function () {
  if (click == 0) { 
    //for first click change the onclick function to stopAnimation() for the element which is clicked and remove onclick functions of others
    $('.particletext').attr("onclick", "");
    $(this).attr("onclick", "stopAnimation(this)");
    click++;
  } else { //for second click decrease the click to 0
    click--;
  }
  
})

function stopAnimation(element) {
  $(element).children('span').remove(); //remove animating particles
  
  //for second click re-add onclick functions to all elements
  $('.hearts').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "hearts()");
    $(this).attr("onclick");
  })
  
  $('.bubbles').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "bubbles()");
    $(this).attr("onclick");
  })
  $('.sunbeams').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "sunbeams()");
  })
  $('.confetti').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "confetti()");
  })
  $('.fire').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "fire()");
  })
}

function bubbles() { 
$.each($(".particletext.bubbles"), function(){
var bubblecount = 4;
for(var i = 0; i <= bubblecount; i++) {
var size = ((Math.floor( Math.random() * (80 - 40 + 1) ) + 40)/10);
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + 27 + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (95 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
}); 
}


function hearts() {
$.each($(".particletext.hearts"), function(){
var heartcount = 3;
for(var i = 0; i <= heartcount; i++) {
var size = ((Math.floor( Math.random() * (120 - 60 + 1) ) + 60)/10);
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + 11 + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (95 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function confetti() {
$.each($(".particletext.confetti"), function(){
var confetticount = 4;
for(var i = 0; i <= confetticount; i++) {
$(this).append('<span class="particle c' +(Math.floor( Math.random() * (2 - 1 + 1) ) + 1) + '" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (50 - 10 + 1) ) + 10) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (100 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (8 - 6 + 1) ) + 6)+ 'px; height:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (4 - 3+ 1) ) + 3) + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function fire() {
$.each($(".particletext.fire"), function(){
var firecount = 2;
for(var i = 0; i <= firecount; i++) {
var size = Math.floor( Math.random() * (12 - 8 + 1) ) + 8;
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (70 - 40 + 1) ) + 40) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (1 +20 + 11) ) + 1) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function sunbeams() {
$.each($(".particletext.sunbeams"), function(){
var linecount = 3;
for(var i = 0; i <= linecount; i++) {
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (0 + 40 + 1) ) - 40) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (100 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' +(Math.floor( Math.random() * (2 - 1 + 1) ) + 1 )+ 'px; height:' + 35 + '%;animation-delay: -' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}
```

```css
.particletext {
text-align: center;
font-size: 48px;
position: relative;
}
.particletext.bubbles > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(33, 149, 243, 0.603);
-webkit-animation: bubbles 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: bubbles 3s ease-in infinite;
border-radius: 100%;
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(204,42,93,1);
-webkit-animation: hearts 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: hearts 3s ease-in infinite;
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:before,.particletext.hearts > .particle:after {
position: absolute;
content: '';
border-radius: 100px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(204,42,93,1);
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:before {
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:after {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.particletext.lines > .particle {
position: absolute; 
background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.5);
-webkit-animation: lines 3s linear infinite;
animation: lines 3s linear infinite;
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
-webkit-animation: confetti 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: confetti 3s ease-in infinite;
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle.c1 {
background-color: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.5);
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle.c2 {
background-color: rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.5);
}
.particletext.fire > .particle {
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(7, 141, 255, 0.5);
border-radius: 40px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
-webkit-animation: fires 0.8s linear infinite;
animation: fires 0.8s linear infinite;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
opacity: 0;
}
.particletext.fire > .particle:before {
position: absolute;
content: '';
top: 60%;
left: 40%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
border-radius: 40px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
background-color: rgba(0, 66, 251, 0.5);
}
.particletext.sunbeams > .particle {
position: absolute;
background-color:#dc3dd5;
border-radius: 100px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-animation: sunbeams 3s linear infinite;
animation: sunbeams 3s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bubbles {
0% {
opacity: 0;
}
20% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%);
transform: translate(0, -20%);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%);
transform: translate(0, -1000%);
}
} 
@keyframes bubbles {
0% {
opacity: 0;
}
20% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%);
transform: translate(0, -20%);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%);
transform: translate(0, -1000%);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes hearts {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
}
20% {
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
 transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
}
}
@keyframes hearts {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
}
20% {
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes lines {
0%, 50%, 100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
transform: translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
transform: translateY(100%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
}
@keyframes lines {
0%, 50%, 100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
transform: translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
transform: translateY(100%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes confetti {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
}
10% {
opacity: 1;
}
35% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
}
80% {
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
}
}
@keyframes confetti {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
}
10% {
opacity: 1;
}
35% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
}
80% {
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fires {
0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
opacity: 1;
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
opacity: 1;
}
}
@keyframes fires {
0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
opacity: 1;
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
opacity: 1;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes sunbeams {
0% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
}
0%,14%,17%,43%,53%,71%,80%,94%,100% {
opacity: 0;
}
6%,15%,24%,28%,48%,55%,78%,82%,99% {
opacity: 1;
}
}
@keyframes sunbeams {
0% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
}
0%,14%,17%,43%,53%,71%,80%,94%,100% {
opacity: 0;
}
6%,15%,24%,28%,48%,55%,78%,82%,99% {
opacity: 1;
}
}

ul.socialIcons {
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.socialIcons li {
background: #fff;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 25px;
font-size: 12px;
}


.socialIcons li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="socialIcons">
<li class="particletext hearts" onclick="hearts()"><a>A</a></li>
<li class="particletext bubbles" onclick="bubbles()"><a>B</a></li>
<li class="particletext sunbeams" onclick="sunbeams()"><a>C</a></li>
<li class="particletext confetti" onclick="confetti()"><a>D</a></li>
<li class="particletext fire" onclick="fire()"><a>E</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you face any problem feel free to comment @aryana .

Comment: if clicked  multiple time on any one of the disabled  alphabet it gets activated along with  whichever is active.

Comment: I have fixed the problem in my new answer. Thanks @Debendra for detecting the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the revised code. I add comments to separate my code in js file.

```js
//my code starts here

var click = 0; //track the click
var elementClassName;

$('.particletext').click(function () {
  if (click == 0) { 
    elementClassName = $(this).attr('class');
    
    //for first click change the onclick function to stopAnimation() for the element which is clicked and remove onclick functions of others
    $('.particletext').attr("onclick", "");
    $(this).attr("onclick", "stopAnimation(this)");
    click++;
  } else { //for second click decrease the click to 0
    if ($(this).attr('class') == elementClassName) {
        click--;
    }
  }
  
})


//my code ends here

function stopAnimation(element) {
  $(element).children('span').remove(); //remove animating particles
  
  //for second click re-add onclick functions to all elements
  $('.hearts').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "hearts()");
    $(this).attr("onclick");
  })
  
  $('.bubbles').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "bubbles()");
    $(this).attr("onclick");
  })
  $('.sunbeams').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "sunbeams()");
  })
  $('.confetti').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "confetti()");
  })
  $('.fire').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("onclick", "fire()");
  })
}

function bubbles() { 
$.each($(".particletext.bubbles"), function(){
var bubblecount = 4;
for(var i = 0; i <= bubblecount; i++) {
var size = ((Math.floor( Math.random() * (80 - 40 + 1) ) + 40)/10);
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + 27 + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (95 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
}); 
}


function hearts() {
$.each($(".particletext.hearts"), function(){
var heartcount = 3;
for(var i = 0; i <= heartcount; i++) {
var size = ((Math.floor( Math.random() * (120 - 60 + 1) ) + 60)/10);
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + 11 + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (95 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function confetti() {
$.each($(".particletext.confetti"), function(){
var confetticount = 4;
for(var i = 0; i <= confetticount; i++) {
$(this).append('<span class="particle c' +(Math.floor( Math.random() * (2 - 1 + 1) ) + 1) + '" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (50 - 10 + 1) ) + 10) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (100 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (8 - 6 + 1) ) + 6)+ 'px; height:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (4 - 3+ 1) ) + 3) + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function fire() {
$.each($(".particletext.fire"), function(){
var firecount = 2;
for(var i = 0; i <= firecount; i++) {
var size = Math.floor( Math.random() * (12 - 8 + 1) ) + 8;
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (70 - 40 + 1) ) + 40) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (1 +20 + 11) ) + 1) + '%;width:' + size + 'px; height:' + size + 'px;animation-delay: ' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}

function sunbeams() {
$.each($(".particletext.sunbeams"), function(){
var linecount = 3;
for(var i = 0; i <= linecount; i++) {
$(this).append('<span class="particle" style="top:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (0 + 40 + 1) ) - 40) + '%; left:' + (Math.floor( Math.random() * (100 - 0 + 1) ) + 0) + '%;width:' +(Math.floor( Math.random() * (2 - 1 + 1) ) + 1 )+ 'px; height:' + 35 + '%;animation-delay: -' + 0.1 + 's;"></span>');
}
});
}
```

```css
.particletext {
text-align: center;
font-size: 48px;
position: relative;
}
.particletext.bubbles > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(33, 149, 243, 0.603);
-webkit-animation: bubbles 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: bubbles 3s ease-in infinite;
border-radius: 100%;
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(204,42,93,1);
-webkit-animation: hearts 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: hearts 3s ease-in infinite;
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:before,.particletext.hearts > .particle:after {
position: absolute;
content: '';
border-radius: 100px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(204,42,93,1);
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:before {
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.particletext.hearts > .particle:after {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.particletext.lines > .particle {
position: absolute; 
background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.5);
-webkit-animation: lines 3s linear infinite;
animation: lines 3s linear infinite;
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
-webkit-animation: confetti 3s ease-in infinite;
animation: confetti 3s ease-in infinite;
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle.c1 {
background-color: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.5);
}
.particletext.confetti > .particle.c2 {
background-color: rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.5);
}
.particletext.fire > .particle {
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(7, 141, 255, 0.5);
border-radius: 40px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
-webkit-animation: fires 0.8s linear infinite;
animation: fires 0.8s linear infinite;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
opacity: 0;
}
.particletext.fire > .particle:before {
position: absolute;
content: '';
top: 60%;
left: 40%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
border-radius: 40px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
background-color: rgba(0, 66, 251, 0.5);
}
.particletext.sunbeams > .particle {
position: absolute;
background-color:#dc3dd5;
border-radius: 100px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-animation: sunbeams 3s linear infinite;
animation: sunbeams 3s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bubbles {
0% {
opacity: 0;
}
20% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%);
transform: translate(0, -20%);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%);
transform: translate(0, -1000%);
}
} 
@keyframes bubbles {
0% {
opacity: 0;
}
20% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%);
transform: translate(0, -20%);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%);
transform: translate(0, -1000%);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes hearts {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
}
20% {
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
 transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
}
}
@keyframes hearts {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, 0%) rotate(45deg);
}
20% {
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -20%) rotate(45deg);
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(0, -1000%) rotate(45deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes lines {
0%, 50%, 100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
transform: translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
transform: translateY(100%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
}
@keyframes lines {
0%, 50%, 100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
transform: translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
transform: translateY(100%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes confetti {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
}
10% {
opacity: 1;
}
35% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
}
80% {
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
}
}
@keyframes confetti {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(0%) rotate(0deg);
}
10% {
opacity: 1;
}
35% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
transform: translateY(-800%) rotate(270deg);
}
80% {
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
transform: translateY(2000%) rotate(1440deg);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fires {
0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
opacity: 1;
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
opacity: 1;
}
}
@keyframes fires {
0% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(0%);
}
25% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-5%);
opacity: 1;
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-10%);
}
75% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-20%);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
transform: rotate(-70deg) translateY(-40%);
opacity: 1;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes sunbeams {
0% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
}
0%,14%,17%,43%,53%,71%,80%,94%,100% {
opacity: 0;
}
6%,15%,24%,28%,48%,55%,78%,82%,99% {
opacity: 1;
}
}
@keyframes sunbeams {
0% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
transform: translateY(-40%) rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
transform: translateY(40%) rotate(360deg);
}
0%,14%,17%,43%,53%,71%,80%,94%,100% {
opacity: 0;
}
6%,15%,24%,28%,48%,55%,78%,82%,99% {
opacity: 1;
}
}

ul.socialIcons {
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.socialIcons li {
background: #fff;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 25px;
font-size: 12px;
}


.socialIcons li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="socialIcons">
<li class="particletext hearts" onclick="hearts()"><a>A</a></li>
<li class="particletext bubbles" onclick="bubbles()"><a>B</a></li>
<li class="particletext sunbeams" onclick="sunbeams()"><a>C</a></li>
<li class="particletext confetti" onclick="confetti()"><a>D</a></li>
<li class="particletext fire" onclick="fire()"><a>E</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is great!  I was wondering whether it is possible to deactivate the active one when any of the disabled one is clicked and that disabled one should become active

Comment: I've changed the given code according to your requirement and post it as a new answer. If that works for you, please make it active answer and upvote it. If you face any problem further inform me. Thank you :) @aryana